# rationalized K-Theory of the group ring of finite cyclic groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-k-theory

I am interested in calculating the rationalized algebraic K-Theory groups of the group ring of $\mathbb Z/n$, that is $K_i(\mathbb Z[\mathbb Z/n])\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ for any natural number $n\geq 2$. What is known about the rationalized K-Theory of $\mathbb Z[\mathbb Z/n]$ for an arbitrary $n$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rationalized K-theory of finite groups is known: Let $G$ be a finite group and $n \ge 2$. 
$$K_n(\mathbb Z G)\otimes \mathbb Q =
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{Q}^r & n\equiv 1(4) \newline 
\mathbb{Q}^c & n\equiv 3(4) \newline 
0 & n \text{ even}
\end{cases}$$
where $r$ is the number of irreducible real representations of $G$ and $c$ of them are of complex type (see Theorem 2.2 [here](http://folk.uio.no/bjoernj/papers/kg.pdf)).

Now let $G=\mathbb{Z}/n$. If $n$ is odd then $r=(n+1)/2$ and $c=(n-1)/2$. If $n$ is even, then $r=(n+2)/2$ and $c=(n-2)/2$.

Comment: Thank you! I also edited the question and took out my wrong attempt for the calculation.

Comment: Hi Ralph, is there any integral information known about these group rings?